# Custom Table of Contents with horizontal spacing between chapter number and chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf

I am trying to custom table of contents as shown in the given image for a project report. I'm to new to latex. can someone help me with latex code for it.

[image: toc that i want]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: What have you tried? You have to show that you have done something.